# Data captured outside Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Python for starters, when I got this DataFrame from Yahoo Finance, the Date shows up outside the DataFrame. This is leading me to get KeyError: 'Date' when I try to write this line of code

Close_Price['Year'] = Close_Price['Date'].dt.year

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/69172ff45925a2b3ba3b60c2bf46a9a8 Sorry this is the DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

I think because the Date column is the index column, maybe you should convert it into normal column like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461165/how-to-convert-index-of-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-column)

Comment: Thank you so much